# Has anyone used Fl_Native_File_Chooser and set the start up directory?

Tags: fltk

I am trying to use the Fl_Native_File_Chooser from fltk 1.3 and the class works fine except for setting the start directory.

```
    const char *start_dir = "C:\\Program Files (x86)";
    Fl_Native_File_Chooser native(Fl_Native_File_Chooser::BROWSE_DIRECTORY);
    native.directory( start_dir );
    native.title( "Select a directory");

    native.type(Fl_Native_File_Chooser::BROWSE_DIRECTORY);

    std::string directoryName;
    switch ( native.show() ) 
    {
    case -1: break; //fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", native.errmsg()); break; // ERROR
    case  1: break; //fprintf(stderr, "*** CANCEL\n"); fl_beep(); break;    // CANCEL
    default:                            // PICKED FILE
        if ( native.filename() ) directoryName = native.filename();
        break;
    }
    std::cout << directoryName << std::endl;
```

I've looked into the code.
In Fl_Native_File_Chooser_WIN32.cxx and int Fl_Native_File_Chooser::showdir()
I don't understand why the _binf.pidlRoot is not set.
I have looked at Fl_Native_File_Chooser::showfile() but the way the dialoge is setup is different.

So has anyone successfully set the startup directory for the Fl_Native_File_Chooser when you are browsing for a directory?

The strange thing to me is that the normal Fl_File_Chooser works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, although I'm not sure what you mean by "_binf.pidlRoot".
What do you expect the code to do, and what does it actually do? Is there any code before or after the part that you posted? This could affect things...

Comment: What compiler are you using?  I am using VS2008 Professional.